# having some issue with flexbox layout in react-native

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I am trying to make this highlighted line to stretch full width. I have tried many possible ways to come around it but could not get it as desired.

[image] [image]

Here is my code from `render()` method.

```
return (
  <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: imageURI}} />
          <View style={styles.content}>  
            <Text style={styles.title}>{news.title}</Text>
            <View style={styles.itemIcons}>
              <View  style={styles.companyView}>
                <Image
                  source={{uri: news.category[0].sourceImage}}
                  style={ styles.iconsImage} />
                <Text style={styles.iconsText}>{news.category_name}</Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.iconsTextRight}>{this.formatDate(news.pubDate)}</Text>

            </View>
            <Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
  </ScrollView>
);
```

And here are my styles for this.

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
},
content: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',

  padding: 10
},
image: {
    width: width,
    height: custom_height,
    // padding: 10
},
title: {
 marginBottom: 15
},
itemIcons: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',

  marginBottom: 15
},
iconsImage: {
  height: 25,
  width: 30,
  marginRight: 10,
},
iconsText: {
  fontSize: 12,
  color: "#686666",
  alignSelf: 'flex-end'
},
companyView: {flex:1,flexDirection:'row'},
dateView: {flex:1,alignSelf: 'flex-end'},
iconsTextRight: {
  fontSize: 12,
  color: "#686666",
  alignSelf: 'flex-end'
},
description: {
    padding: 2,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#323'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change container style to

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
}
```

Then the view will be aligned as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

try this in **itemIcons** class
**justify-content:'space-between'**

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. But this does not work I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't work with whole of your code, but as per the screenshot you posted, I was able to achieve this.

[image]

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',paddingTop:100,justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:'center'}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Image source={require('./images/tiger.jpg')} style={{width:40,height:40}} />
                <Text>Roche</Text>
              </View>
              <Text>25 Mar 2016, 18:16</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
```

Try to replicate this in your code and see if it works.